# Trying to Install TensorFlow 1.15 using Conda but always getting 1.9.0

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, conda

I am using Conda to install Tensorflow 1.15 to a new environment using the following commands:

```
conda create -p ./env_tf python=3.6.5 -y
conda activate ./env_tf
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.15 -y
```

The result of `conda list`:

```
(C:\Projects\pythonEnvDeployment\env_tf) PS C:\Projects\pythonEnvDeployment> conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Projects\pythonEnvDeployment\env_tf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.11.28               py36_0    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0
gast                      0.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.1.8                      py_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.23.0           py36h3db2c7e_0    conda-forge
h5py                      2.10.0          nompi_py36h422b98e_101    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_ha405e13_1104    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.11.2               h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               9.0.1                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.5                      281    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.3.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
numpy                     1.17.5           py36hc71023c_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1d               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.3.1                   py36_0
protobuf                  3.11.2           py36he025d50_0    conda-forge
pyreadline                2.1                   py36_1001    conda-forge
python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0
scipy                     1.3.1            py36h29ff71c_0    conda-forge
setuptools                44.0.0                   py36_0
six                       1.14.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               1.15.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                1.15.0          gpu_py36h2b26d6b_0
tensorflow-base           1.15.0          gpu_py36h1afeea4_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.15.1             pyh2649769_0
tensorflow-gpu            1.15.0               h0d30ee6_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.6                   py36_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1006    conda-forge
```

However, when I am trying to verify the TF version on the python prompt, I am getting 1.9.0:

```
(C:\Projects\pythonEnvDeployment\env_tfPS C:\Projects\pythonEnvDeployment> python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>>> tf.__version__
'1.9.0'
```

Is there a step I am missing in this process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are running the wrong Python instance (from `C:\Users\sarth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36`, the environment name `env_tf` is not there).  Check your PATH variables.  Also, check where you are running Python from via: `import sys; sys.executable`

Answer (score 1):

As commented @James, looks you have activated different conda environment.

Follow the below steps to install Tensorflow using conda

```
#Set Up Anaconda Environment
$conda create -n env_tf python=3.6.5

#Activate the new Environment
$source activate env_tf

#Install tensorflow
(env_tf) $ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.15

#Verify Tensorflow installation
(env_tf) $ python
>>import tensorflow as tf
>>tf.__version__
1.15
```